# How to use optgroup in reactjs with dynamic data

Tags: html, reactjs, arrays, html-select

Hello I want to know how I can get multiple data in group in select option tags
What I am getting is like this
[image]

but What I want is to group all data under same category like there is four cohort with different data I want just one cohort and all four data under that.

What I coded is:

```
<select name="" id="" onClick={(e)=>{console.log(e.target.value)}}>
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select X Axis Segments</option>
       {dimension.map(((d,index)=>(
            <optgroup label={d.category}>
               <option value={d.apiName} key={index}>
                 {d.uiName}
               </option>
            </optgroup>
      )))}
</select>
```

Do I need to make object first and map accordingly first then fetch it on select option tag??
or is there any simple way

Do let me know if you need any other code reference

Answer (score 0):

U need to group ur data into categories before u render them

```js
import _ from "lodash";

const data = [
  {
    name: "Audi",
    category: "car"
  },
  {
    name: "BMW",
    category: "car"
  },
  {
    name: "Banana",
    category: "fruit"
  },
  {
    name: "Apple",
    category: "fruit"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const categories = _.groupBy(data, "category");
  console.log(categories);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select>
        {Object.keys(categories).map((category) => (
          <optgroup label={category}>
            {categories[category].map(({ name }) => (
              <option value={name}>{name}</option>
            ))}
          </optgroup>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```